# How to manipulate variables of a solution given by DSolve?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I have a set of coupled differential equations which I would like to use its solution to plot a function. I already have obtained the desired plot but I want to improve it a little. I would like to be able to manipulate some variables of the equations. I first define the following functions

```
f[w_, a_, l_] := (6 a)/(w^3 l^2 (4 + a^2 l^2)^(5/2)) (w l (-2 + a^2 l^2)*(4 + a^2 l^2)^(1/2)Cos[(2 w)/a ArcSinh[(a l)/2]] + (4 + 4 w^2 l^2 a^2 l^2 (4 + w^2 l^2)) Sinh[(2 w)/a ArcSinh[(a l)/2]])    
A1[a_, w_, l_] := w^3/(12 Pi) (1 + a^2/w^2) Coth[(Pi w)/a] 
A2[a_, w_, l_] := w^3/(12 Pi ) f[w, a, l] Coth[(Pi w)/a]  
B1[a_, w_, l_] :=  w^3/(12 Pi) (1 + a^2/w^2)
B2[a_, w_, l_] := ((w^3)/(12 Pi )) f[w, a, l]
```

then I fix the parameter (these ones are what I want to manipulate)

```
a = 7; w = 5; l = 1/5
```

Then I solve the equation using NDSolve

```
sol = NDSolve[{
   GG'[t] == 
    2 ((A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) AA[
         t] - 2 (A1[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l]) GG[
         t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] + 
          B2[a, w, l]) SS[t]),AA'[t] == (2 (-A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l]) AA[
    t] + (A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) EE[t]+(A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) GG[t]),
SS'[t] == 
 2 ((A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) EE[
      t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) GG[
      t] - 2 (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l]) SS[t]),EE'[t] == 
 2 ((A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) AA[t] - 
    2 (A1[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l]) EE[
      t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) SS[
      t]),AS'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] AS[t],
SA'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] AS[t],
GE'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] GE[t],EG'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] EG[t], GG[0] == 0, EE[0] == 0, AS[0] == 0 , 
  SA[0] == 0, AA[0] == 0, SS[0] == 1, EG[0] == 0, 
  GE[0] == 0}, {GG[t], EE[t], AS[t] , SA[t], AA[t], SS[t], EG[t], 
  GE[t]}, {t, 0, 100}
 ]
```

Then I plot the following

```
Plot[Evaluate[{Max[0, 
     Sqrt[(AA[t] - SS[t])^2 - (AS[t] - SA[t])^2 ] - 
      2 Sqrt[GG[t] EE[t]],
       2 Abs[GE[t]] - Sqrt[(AA[t] + SS[t])^2 - (AS[t] + SA[t])^2 ]] /. 
    sol}], {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The only thing I want to do is to plot the same function for different values of a and w. I have tried to use DSolve to build an analytical function depending on the a and w variables but it was not effective. My idea was that if I can obtain the analytical result I also would be able to plot using ListDensityPlot for a fixed value of t some figure showing the dependence of the function in the variables a and w.

Any idea how can I solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and [`Manipulate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Manipulate.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[w_, a_, 
  l_] := (6 a)/(w^3 l^2 (4 + a^2 l^2)^(5/2)) (w l (-2 + 
       a^2 l^2)*(4 + a^2 l^2)^(1/2) Cos[(2 w)/a ArcSinh[(a l)/2]] + (4 + 
       4 w^2 l^2 a^2 l^2 (4 + w^2 l^2)) Sinh[(2 w)/a ArcSinh[(a l)/2]])
A1[a_, w_, l_] := w^3/(12 Pi) (1 + a^2/w^2) Coth[(Pi w)/a]
A2[a_, w_, l_] := w^3/(12 Pi) f[w, a, l] Coth[(Pi w)/a]
B1[a_, w_, l_] := w^3/(12 Pi) (1 + a^2/w^2)
B2[a_, w_, l_] := ((w^3)/(12 Pi)) f[w, a, l]
```

Solving,

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{GG'[t] == 
     2 ((A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) AA[t] - 
        2 (A1[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l]) GG[
          t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) SS[t]),
     AA'[t] == (2 (-A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l]) AA[
         t] + (A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) EE[
         t] + (A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) GG[t]), 
    SS'[t] == 
     2 ((A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) EE[
          t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) GG[
          t] - 2 (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l]) SS[t]), 
    EE'[t] == 
     2 ((A1[a, w, l] - A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] + B2[a, w, l]) AA[t] - 
        2 (A1[a, w, l] + B1[a, w, l]) EE[
          t] + (A1[a, w, l] + A2[a, w, l] - B1[a, w, l] - B2[a, w, l]) SS[t]),
     AS'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] AS[t], SA'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] AS[t], 
    GE'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] GE[t], EG'[t] == -4 A1[a, w, l] EG[t], 
    GG[0] == 0, EE[0] == 0, AS[0] == 0, SA[0] == 0, AA[0] == 0, SS[0] == 1, 
    EG[0] == 0, GE[0] == 0}, {GG, EE, AS, SA, AA, SS, EG, GE}, {t, 0, 1}, {a, 
    w, l}, WorkingPrecision -> 15];
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Max[0, 
    Sqrt[(AA[a, w, l][t] - SS[a, w, l][t])^2 - (AS[a, w, l][t] - 
          SA[a, w, l][t])^2] - 2 Sqrt[GG[a, w, l][t] EE[a, w, l][t]], 
    2 Abs[GE[a, w, l][t]] - 
     Sqrt[(AA[a, w, l][t] + SS[a, w, l][t])^2 - (AS[a, w, l][t] + 
          SA[a, w, l][t])^2]] /. sol, {t, 0, 0.5}, PlotRange -> All],
 {{a, 7}, 1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{w, 5}, 1, 10, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{l, 0.2}, 0.1, 1, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this command! Thank you very much!